# Uniswap V2 pool priceImpact

Tags: uniswap

How do you calculate the priceImpact on Uniswap v2 pools? I can't find documentation to help me. The price impact appears on the UI when you select two tokens you want to swap.

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the price impact using the constant product formula.

Imagine you have a pool with 2,000,000 USDC and 1,000 ETH. The price of 1 ETH is 2,000 USDC.

Using the constant product formula (x*y=k) where x is USDC and y is ETH, k is 2,000,000,000.

Now, I'm going to swap 10,000 USDC for ETH.

2,000,000 USDC + 10,000 USDC = 2,010,000 USDC

x * y = k => y = k/x = 2,000,000,000/2,010,000 = 995.02 ETH

We receive 1,000 ETH - 995.02 ETH = 4.98 ETH

Price Impact = 4.98 ETH / 995.02 ETH = 0.5%

This [article](https://dailydefi.org/articles/price-impact-and-how-to-calculate/) covers price impact in more detail.

Comment: but constant product formula is for Uniswap V2 only, no? 
In Uniswap V3 pools have limited price ranges

Comment: @fshabashev Sorry, the question above should be "v2" not "v3". Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Pour le price impact je dois manquer un truc mais 4.98 ETH / 995.02 ETH ça fait 0.005004 et non 0.5% non? Donc il faut le multiplier par 100 ensuite?

Answer (score 2):

First is important to differentiate between price impact and price slippage.

First one being responsible of the impact you have within the pool with your trade size (the bigger the trade the bigger the price impact).

Price slippage would be the change made in the price by the market. There we would need to talk about the expected slippage vs the real slippage. (Imagine someone swaps before your trade gets executed and you incur in a bigger slippage than expected)

More info [here](https://support.uniswap.org/hc/en-us/articles/8643794102669-Price-Impact-vs-Price-Slippage)

Following what Khanh said, the calculations for price impact given by Anthony is innacurate. With zero fees and not taking into account slippage, the price impact would be calculated as the % in difference from the original spot price (2000) and the current spot price after the trade (2009.64).

So 2009.64/2000-1 = 0.482%

Answer (score 1):

The price impact calculation is mostly similar to that of Anthony but the final calculation of price impact is inaccurate. The correct way is to determine the executed price and initial price ratio. In his example, assuming zero LP fee (usually it's 0.3% for Uniswap V2), the original price was 2,000,000 / 1,000 = 2,000; however, your executed price was 10,000/4.98 = 2008.032. So the price slippage is
2008.032/2000 - 1 = 0.4%.
Hope this helps.